Inequality in Sobolev-Slobodeckij norm in separate variables
I'm trying to follow the proof of trace inequality in fractional Sobolev spaces. By assuming the smoothness of the domain and using partition of identity, the proof is reduced to the senario in an exercise (3.6 in Finite elements I by Ern and Guermond). The solution is accessible online which I have no problem following but in the solution to exercise 3.6, it mentioned an inequality that I cannot derive without any hint:
\begin{align} \tag{1}
    \int_F \int_0^a \int_0^a \frac{ | v( z, x_d) - v ( z, y_d ) |^p  }{ | x_d - y_d |^{sp+1} } dzdx_ddy_d \leq c(s,p) |v|_{ W^{s,p} (D) }^p
\end{align}
where $ D = F \times ( 0 ,a ) \subset \mathbb{R}^d $, $ x = ( z, x_d ) \in \mathbb{R}^d $ with $ z \in \mathbb{R}^{d-1} $, $ s \in ( 0, 1 ) $, $ p \in [ 1, \infty ) $, $ sp > 1 $, $ a > 0 $ and $ |\cdot|_{ W^{s,p} (D) } $ defined by
$$ \vert v \vert_{ W^{s,p} (\Omega) }^p = \int_\Omega \int_\Omega \frac{ | v(x) - v(y) |^p }{ |x-y|^{sp+d} } dxdy $$
is the Sobolev-Slobodeckij seminorm, which is the key to this proof. In $L^p$-norms, this inequality is trivial
$$ \Vert \Vert v( \cdot_z, \cdot_x ) \Vert_{L^p(x)} \Vert_{L^p(z)} = \Vert v \Vert_{L^p(z,x)} $$.
I pretty much have no clue how to establish (1). I tried something like expressing LHS by writing $ ( \cdots ) = \tfrac{1}{|F|} \int_F (\cdots) dz' $ and use triangle inequality to get the term we have in the seminorm, but this at the same time gives you another term I don't know how to tackle. Second thing I tried is by noticing that
$$ \int_F \int_F G(z,z') dzdz' = \int_{\Omega} \int_{z=z'-\eta} G(z,z') dz d\eta $$
with suitable $\Omega$ and bound the integral $ \int_F G(z,z) dz $ by $ \int_{z=z'-\eta} G(z,z') dz $ on a subset of $\Omega$ with positive measure using some sort of continuity, which I'm not sure how to do either.
In the solution there is reference to this lemma but I do not have access to the book. Any hint is appreciated thanks!

Your quantity can be written
$$
|u|{L^p(F)}
$$
Where $u(z) = |v(z,\cdot)|{W^{s,p}(I)}$ with $I=(0,a)$. So if $u$ is $0$ somewhere (for instance if if $v$ is $0$ on the boundary of $F$ or if the domain is strictly convex) the by Poincaré inequality it is bounded by $|u|{W^{s,p}(F)}$, and this quantity is I think bounded by $|v|{W^{s,p}(D)}$ (for example because it is true for $s=0$ and $s=1$, and then by interpolation. But there might be a direct proof)

@LL3.14 Thank you for the feedback. I'm not into interpolation theory yet so I'm not sure if I understand what you described. It is true that this inequality is trivially true with $L^p$-norm, full $W^{1,p}$-norm on the right hand side (in your notation). Is this sufficient to apply some sort of interpolation theorem to conclude? Is vanishing at some point in $F$ (which is in general not true) necessary in this case? but yes if there's direct proof I would love to know too. btw I forget to mention that the constant in the inequality should only depend on $s,p$ (edited).
